# Replace manual thermostat with programmable

Tags: heating, cooling

I have a Flair 3-wire thermostat, open common and closed, with 3 terminals marked 4.5.6. 4 black wire=open terminal, 5 white wire=common terminal, 6 red wire= closed.

I want to replace with a programmable thermostat but cannot find any cross references with this configuration. White Rodgers has a diagram for my thermostat but no chart to tell which terminals to use. I have a new 70 series White Rodgers programmable thermostat with the following terminals: R C W2 E Y O/B G and L.

Comment: Can you get us some photos?  Your description is indecipherable...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I tried to rewrite this into English; let me know if I got the details right. And, please add photos of the old and new thermostats.

Comment: Oh, *lovely* -- not the variable air volume systems again!

Comment: Also, is this in a single-family house, or some sort of multi-family building?

Comment: Single family home with two zones

Comment: Not sure how to add photos

Comment: Post the photos on [imgur](http://imgur.com) and put a link in the comments or in your question -- we can do the rest.

Comment: Also, what is actually supplying the heated/cooled air in your house?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to.  The programmable thermostats commonly sold are designed for on/off control of a heating and cooling system.  The Flair line of thermostats are designed to control a Flair damper that is allowing more or less air into the room.  The Open and Closed Signals move the damper in that direction.  I believe the Flair is an variable system, not the on/off a thermostat is designed to control.

You could try an old hack from the days before programmable thermostats.  Mount a 4 watt incandescent nightlight directly below the Flair thermostat and wired into a light timer (or a home automation module).  When the nightlight is on the thermostat will be fooled into thinking the room is a few degrees warmer than it actually is and the real temperature in the room will be "set back" several degrees cooler.

If you have some electronics skill a SPDT relay could have its contacts wired to the Flair wiring.  (Closed to the NC relay terminal, Open to the NO terminal, and common to common.)  A low voltage power supply (under 24V) that matches the coil voltage of the relay could be wired to the could be wired into the R terminal of the thermostat, and then out via either the RH terminal (heat) or Y (cool) and to the coil, then back the the power supply.  This won't work if the thermostat is designed to be powered from the furnace instead of having its own batteries.

Answer (score 0):

### Variable Anger and Venting (of the profane kind)

Unfortunately, the Flair belongs to a class of HVAC systems known generically as Variable Air Volume systems, or VAV for short.  HVAC systems must control three key parameters in order to provide comfort, namely:

- Temperature
- Humidity
- and "Freshness" (i.e. being able to prevent CO2, odors, etal from building up and being recirculated to the point of nobody wanting to be there)

Traditional HVAC systems in old, leaky buildings control temperature, and occasionally provide some way to control humidity semi-independently, leaving freshness to building air leaks.  More modern systems can control temperature and humidity independently of each other, as well as wrangle some control over fresh air delivery separately from the two.

VAVs, on the other hand, multiplex all three parameters for a zone onto one control -- the poor, overworked air damper.  The resulting conflicting demands mean that *something* has to give, most of the time.  (For instance, what do you do when one zone is cold but damp, producing a heavy latent (moisture) load in that zone along with the need for heat, while the other zone is hot and dry, requiring sensible (thermal) cooling and the need for a bit of supplemental humidity?)

The simplest solution to this problem is to rip out the Flair and throw it in a scrapmetal bin -- leaving you with a conventional, single-zone forced air system.  If you really find the need for a multiple zone system -- there are better options. One is completely independent forced-air systems for each zone -- this sounds costly, but you can use smaller conventional systems or even ducted mini-splits to handle the smaller loads presented by each zone.  It's also going to be familiar to the next tech who has to fix it.

The other option is a system that moves only water or refrigerant across zone boundaries instead of trying to push air across them, with one air handler for each zone.  This is basically a house-sized version of the common four-pipe hydronic heating/cooling system seen in commercial work if you use water as a medium, or what is called Variable Refrigerant Volume (VRV) in a refrigerant-based system.  The main downside here is that most residential HVAC folk don't deal with full-hydronic (i.e. hydronic heating *and* cooling) or VRV systems -- you may need to use a commercial mechanical contractor for installation and maintenance of such a thing.  It also requires more intricate controls (albeit still not quite as bad as the Flair), but allows more plant centralization, which may be beneficial if there are limits on where combustion exhausts can be put, for instance.

If sending the Flair to the dustbin of history is not an option -- then, playing tricks on the existing thermostat is your only choice, unless you wish to try to reverse-engineer the whole darn thing.  (Incidentally, this is why I hate HVAC systems of any kind that rely on proprietary, one-off controls -- when the control stops doing what you want it to do, you're left with a giant paperweight in your furnace room instead of a small paperweight on your wall.)